# iOs OpenGL ES 2.0 blending with shader on device and on simulator

Tags: ios, opengl-es, shader, blending

Here is the fragment of fragment shader code (I need make blending in the shader):

```
float a = texture2D(tMask, texCoords).x; // opacity of current pixel from mask texture.
if ( a == 0.0)
    discard;
else {
    vec4 dst_clr = texture2D(tBkgText, posCoords); // color of current pixel in current framebuffer.
    vec4 src_clr = vec4(vColor.rgb, sOpacity);
    gl_FragColor = src_clr * a + dst_clr * (1.0 - a);
}
```

Here are the blending function and equation:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
```

And here are results on device (left) and on simulator (right):

[image: on device]
[image: on simulator]

How to make so that it works like on an emulator?

**UPDATE:**

I've removed `discard`:

```
float a = texture2D(tMask, texCoords).x; // opacity of current pixel from mask texture.
vec4 dst_clr = texture2D(tBkgText, posCoords); // color of current pixel in current framebuffer.
vec4 src_clr = vec4(vColor.rgb, sOpacity);
gl_FragColor = src_clr * a + dst_clr * (1.0 - a);
```

Now result on the device looks like:

[image: on device without "discard"]

Comment: Is blending enabled? Also, `discard()` can be really expensive on iOS devices, as can an `if()` statement, so you might be better off removing that condition and just always passing the alpha value through to your calculations, even if it is 0.

Comment: Yes, of course, blending is enabled. You can see this on the simulator example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem with adding `glFlush` after `glDrawArrays`. The problem was that the texture was not updated when the drawing occurs in its associated framebuffer.